# JQuery AJAX load method error: cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem using the JQuery AJAX load method to update part of the webpage with new html.  I get the following JavaScript error in the dev console:

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (site.js:4)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLLIElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSwitchView").click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $("#divViewContainer").load(url);
    });
});
```

This script should run when any of these buttons are pressed:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tasks <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="btnSwitchView"><a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Requirements", "Tasks")">Requirements</a></li>
                    <li class="btnSwitchView"><a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Patterns", "Tasks")">Patterns</a></li>
                    <li class="btnSwitchView"><a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Suppliers", "Tasks")">Suppliers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Administration <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="btnSwitchView"><a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Roles", "Administration")">Roles</a></li>
                    <li class="btnSwitchView"><a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Users", "Administration")">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And the `divViewContainer` div should be where the new html is displayed:

```
<body>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("PartialViews/NavigationPartial.cshtml");
    }

    <div class="container divViewContainer">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("PartialViews/SaveBarPartial.cshtml");
    }

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: You do not have a div with **Id** `divViewContainer`, and you are using an Id jQuery selector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery `load` method internally calls the `indexOf` method on the first parameter passed to it (*the url*).

```
h = a.indexOf(" ")
```

Your `click` event handler is wired up to the elements with `btnSwitchView` css class, which is the `li` items in the markup you shared. So when the click event happens, `$(this)` is the jQuery object of the clicked `li` and that does not have a data attribute for `url`. Your current code will give **`undefined`** as the value of `url` variable and the behind the scene code of `load` method is trying to call `indexOf` on `undefined`, hence you are getting the error messgage **"Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"**

You should get the link (`a`) element inside the clicked list item  and read data attribute from that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSwitchView").click(function () {

        //$(this) is the listitem(li) element
        var url = $(this).find("a").data("url");
        $(".divViewContainer").load(url);  

    });
});
```

Or find the `a` tags inside those list items and wire up the click event to that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSwitchView").find("a").click(function () {

        //$(this) is the link(a) element
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $(".divViewContainer").load(url);

    });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSwitchView>a").click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $(".divViewContainer").load(url);
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that the `find` method gets all the descendants matching the selector expression. You should always try to use as specific as you can when writing jQuery selector. If you are absolutely sure the a tags are going to be the direct children of the li item, you might consider using `children` instead of `find`. The `children` method will search only one level down. I personally would be giving a css class to the `a` elements and use that directly like this

```
$("a.myAjaxLinks").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefaul();
   var url=$(this).data("url");
});
```

Also you are using the Id selector (`$("#divViewContainer")`) with the `load` method. So make sure your div has the id attribute set (currently you have `divViewContainer` set as the css class

```
<div class="container divViewContainer" id="divViewContainer">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Now you can use the Id selector

```
$("#divViewContainer").load(url);
```

Last, but not least, i would keep the `href` attribute value of the link to the urls generated by `Url.Action`. This makes the page more progressive. So even if the jQuery code fails, clicking on the link will take the user to the corresponding page. To read the href attribute value ,you can do something like this

```
$("a.myAjaxLinks").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefaul();
    var url=$(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is set up with this selection:

```
$(".btnSwitchView")
```

In your HTML, that matches a bunch of `li` elements. You then are trying to read `data-url`:

```
var url = $(this).data("url");
```

But notice, that your `li` elements don't have a `data-url` attribute; the `a` element children do. Hence, `url` is not set to a string and `indexOf` fails.

You may just want to update your selector to match those `a` elements so that `$(this)` is what you're expecting:

```
$('.btnSwitchView a').click(...)
```

Comment: I updated my selector using this code, and it works now. Much appreciated!